# Can this multi-tree data structure update in O(log(n)) instead of O(n)?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Consider a doubly linked multi-tree data structure that relates strings with arrays of strings.

**Property 1**: A string can belong to zero or more collections `S` of strings, i.e. `belongsTo: string => Array<S<string>>`.

For example, the strings `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, `'d'`, and `'x'` could be related to the collections `S()`, `S('a')`, `S('x')`, `S('a', 'b')`, and `S('a', 'b', 'c')` such that each of the following expressions returns `true`.

```js
belongsTo('a') // [S()]
belongsTo('x') // [S()]               both 'a' and 'x' belong to S()
belongsTo('b') // [S('a'), S('x')]    'b' belongs to both S('a') and S('x')
belongsTo('c') // [S('a', 'b')]
belongsTo('d') // [S('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

Note that a string can belong to many collections `S`, and a collection `S` can have many strings which belong to it.

**Property 1.1**: `belongsTo` ignores case and order:

```js
belongsTo('c') // S('a', 'b')
belongsTo('C') // S('a', 'b')
```

**Property 1.2**: `belongsTo` is `O(1)`

**Property 2**: `contains` returns an array of strings that belong to the given collection `S`:

```js
contains(S()) // ['a', 'x']
contains(S('a')) // ['b'])
contains(S('a', 'b')) // ['c'])
contains(S('a', 'b', 'c')) // ['d']
contains(S('x')) // ['b']
```

**Property 2.1**: `contains` ignores case and order

```js
contains(S('a', 'b')) // ['c']
contains(S('A', 'B')) // ['c']
contains(S('b', 'a')) // ['c']
```

**Property 2.2**: `contains` is `O(1)`

The above can be accomplished simply with something like the following:

```js
const hashString = s => s.toLowerCase()
const hashArray = arr => sort(arr.map(hashString).concat()).join('_')

const stringIndex = {
  [hashString('a')]: [[]],
  [hashString('b')]: [['a'], ['x']],
  [hashString('c')]: [['a', 'b']],
  [hashString('d')]: [['a', 'b', 'c']],
  [hashString('x')]: [[]]
}

const sIndex = {
  [hashArray([])]: ['a', 'x'],
  [hashArray(['a'])]: ['b'],
  [hashArray(['a', 'b'])]: ['c'],
  [hashArray(['a', 'b', 'c'])]: ['d'],
  [hashArray(['x'])]: ['b']
}

// getters
const belongsTo = s => stringIndex[hashString(s)]
const contains = arr => sIndex[hashArray(arr)]

// others
const adjacent = (arr, s) => arr.concat(s)
const addTo = (arr, s) => { /* adds a string to a collection */ }
const update = (arr, old, new) { /* replace a string in a collection */ }
```

Here's the downside. `update(arr)` (defined above) takes `O(descendants(arr).length)`, where descendants are all of the strings that a given collection `contains`, and all of the strings that the adjacent collections `contain`, and all of the strings that the adjacent collections to the adjacent collections `contain`, etc. (Adjacency here is a similar concept to children, but this is not a tree.)

As soon as I try to abstract away the strings into ids, I lose the hashing functionality that preserves properties 1.1 and 1.2 (unordered and case-insensitive).

**Is there a way to do `update` in `O(1)` or `O(log(n))` instead of `O(descendants)`?**

Comment: What exactly does `update(arr)` do? And what is `arrayIndex`? Is that what your code defines as `sIndex`? I think what you're trying to build here is an index with its corresponding inverted index. Something like one list that tells you which students are in each class, and another list that tells you which classes each student takes. Is that correct?

Comment: `update(arr, old, new)` replaces a string that belongs to a given collection. Good catch `arrayIndex` was supposed to be `sIndex`.

Comment: Yes, I am basically using an index and an inverted index in the current implementation. It leads to a very slow `update` function though, since all "descendants" have to be updated to keep the indices synchronized.